# jQuery animation getting stuck in loop

Tags: jquery, function, animation, scroll

I have a few simple functions on my site that animate this little sprite / make it look like he's teleporting up or down after scroll. The animation works perfectly fine after the doc is ready, but after scroll it gets caught in some kind of glitchy loop somehow. I need to fix this so that it just appears like it does when the page loads. I don't understand why it's glitching like that. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhy1m491/5/), and here is the jQuery:

```
var SpriteVis;
 var ScrollTimer = 2000;

 function tele_in($) { // function to make sprite appear.
     $("#sprite").animate({
         bottom: '0px'
     }, 400, 'linear', function () {
         $("#sprite").css({
             'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
                 'height': '50px',
                 'width': '90px',
                 'left': '300px',
                 'bottom': '80px'
         });
         setTimeout(function () {
             $("#sprite").css({
                 'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/test-sprite.png)',
                     'height': '120px',
                     'width': '96px'
             });
         }, 80);
     });
     SpriteVis = true;
 };

 jQuery(function ($) {

     $(document).ready(function () {
         // Call tele_in()
         tele_in($);
     });

     $(window).scroll(function () {
         ScrollTimer = 2000;
         if (SpriteVis == true) { //if Sprite is present on screen, run the animation sequence to make it disappear.
             $("#sprite").css({

                 'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
                     'height': '50px',
                     'width': '90px',
                     'left': '300px',
                     'bottom': '80px'

             });
             setTimeout(function () {
                 $("#sprite").css({

                     'background-image': 'url(http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/media/images/Teleport-Sprite.png)',
                         'height': '188px',
                         'width': '52px',
                         'left': '330px'

                 });
                 $("#sprite").animate({
                     bottom: '2000px'
                 }, 400, 'linear', function () {});
             }), 80;
             SpriteVis = false;
         } else {
             // Call tele_in() after 3 seconds

             setTimeout(function () {
                 tele_in($);
             }, ScrollTimer);

         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main reason for jumping is that you do not clear your timeouts (you just set more and more). Working example [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhy1m491/7/), I had to use sample images. The part of script you need:

```
var SpriteVis;
var ScrollTimer = 500;
var timeouts = null;

function tele_in($) { // function to make sprite appear.
    $("#sprite").animate({
        bottom: '0px'
    }, 400, 'linear', function () {
        clearTimeout(timeouts);
        timeouts = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sprite").css({
                'background-image': 'url(http://placehold.it/96x120)',
                'height': '120px',
                'width': '96px'
            });
        }, 80);
    });
    SpriteVis = true;
};

jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Call tele_in()
        tele_in($);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (SpriteVis == true) { //if Sprite is present on screen, run the animation sequence to make it disappear.
            clearTimeout(timeouts);
            timeouts = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#sprite").css({
                    'background-image': 'url(http://placehold.it/52x188)',
                    'height': '188px',
                    'width': '52px',
                    'left': '330px'
                });
                $("#sprite").animate({
                    bottom: '1000px'
                }, 1000, 'linear', function () {});
            }), 80;
            SpriteVis = false;
        } else {
            // Call tele_in() after 3 seconds
            clearTimeout(timeouts);
            timeouts = setTimeout(function () {
                tele_in($);
            }, ScrollTimer);

        }
    });
});
```

You've been also setting some styles before setting timouts, I cleared them up.